# MySQL if statement or case when with where condition

Tags: mysql, pdo

```
Table invitation (Primary key: invitation_id)                 

    ---------------------------------------------      
    invitation_id   send_user_id  receive_user_id     
    ---------------------------------------------      
     1                  2             1         
     2                  3             2           
     3                  2             7           
     4                  9             2
    ---------------------------------------------
```

If **send_user_id** value is **2** then I need to get **receive_user_id** and if **receive_user_id** is 2 then I need to get **send_user_id**

How to get this ?

Comment: so why is PDO even tagged here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT invitation_id,
       CASE WHEN send_user_id = 2    THEN receive_user_id
            WHEN receive_user_id = 2 THEN send_user_id
            ELSE -1 END AS output
FROM invitation
```

Note that I am returning `-1` should neither of the two conditions be true, but we can easily replace this with other logic if you provide it.

Comment: I place your code in phpmyadmin SQL section but it's show me error.

Comment: This is a valid MySQL query.  You must be doing something wrong.  What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

try using nested if else if you have multiple conditions to check

```
if // your condition
begin
    //enter you code
end

else if //2nd condition
begin
    // your code
end
else //default condition if none of the above execute
begin 
    //default code
end
```

Comment: if ( send_user_id == 2)
begin
    select * from receive_id where send_user_id == 2
end

else if (receive_user_id  == 2)
begin
   select * from  send_user_id where receive_user_id  == 2
end
else //default condition if none of the above execute
begin 
    //default code
end

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT invitation_id,
 CASE
 WHEN receive_user_id = 2 THEN send_user_id
 WHEN send_user_id = 2    THEN receive_user_id
 END AS output
FROM INVITATION.
```

May be its give proper answer. 
Format code properly.